# ssh-agent isn't running after system boot (Suse 12.1, KDE)

Tags: ssh, kde-plasma, opensuse, ssh-agent

when I call ssh-add I get the following error message:

> Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

It looks like `ssh-agent` isn't running. I don't want to run it manually. I would like to have it running automatically. Does anybody know how to configure that under Suse 12.1 with KDE?

Comment: Uhh you have to give ssh-agent your password so you do have to start it manually.

Comment: No, that is not straight forward. If you had a look in any discussion about this topic you would have seen this.

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

This works fine for me:

cp /etc/X11/xdm/sys.xsession ~/.xsession

From here:

http://tr.opensuse.org/Using_ssh-agent_globally_for_X_session